# Probability of finding the same urn intact after a swap

Tags: probability

> We have two identical urns (with  the same composition, numbers of balls etc). We take a ball from the first urn and move it to the second one. Then we take a ball from the second urn and put it in the first one. What is the probability that the urns remain like they were at the beginning?

I thought that if the urn contained only a type of balls, then the probability of ending up with the same consistency it's clearly $1$ since nothing can change.

So we can assume that in the urns there are two or more types of ball, but we should only care about that type that the first ball (that is about to be moved away) from the first urn is. In short terms if the first ball extracted is white, then we only care about white balls.

So let's call that *reign* of balls **a**. So in the first urn there are $n$ balls, $a$ of the same type of the first ball extracted and $n-a$ that includes any other balls.

Since if an urn remains the same after the swap the other urn remains the same too, so we can mostly ignore what is in the second urn.

But I don't know how to write the idea (hopefully it's the right one) in mathematical terms. Any help?

Comment: The question looks unclear.  Do you have to transfer back exactly the same ball as the original ball with probability $\frac{1}{n+1}$, or just one that looks like it?  If the latter then it depends on what the distributions were originally in the two urns.

Comment: @Henry I forgot about the identical part, the urns are identical and we take a ball from the first urn to the second one. Then we take a random one from the second one to the first one. And it must be one that looks like it (if it was white, then another white). Hope now is clear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the urns have the distribution $n_1+n_2+n_3+\dots+n_k=m$ where $n_i$ is the number of balls of type $i$ in each urn and $m$ is the total number of balls in each urn.

The probability of drawing a ball of type $i$ from the first urn is $\frac{n_i}{m}$. After adding that ball to the second urn, the probability of drawing a ball of the same type from the second urn is $\frac{n_i+1}{m+1}$. The probability of drawing of type $i$ from the first urn then returning a ball of the same type is $\frac{n_i(n_i+1)}{m(m+1)}$.

Then the probability of the final state being indistinguishable from the initial state is the sum of these probabilities for each type:
$$\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{n_i(n_i+1)}{m(m+1)}$$